# Game Center invitation received and processed but match not starting

Tags: ios, game-center, gkmatchmaker

I have hit a snag with my Game Center code and have researched and researched and am using what seems to be the accepted standard approach. I just can't see where things are going wrong.

I am writing a four player card game, and if any player drops out I want them to get invited back into the game.

The scenario is this:
A match is running and all the players are in the game. One player drops out of the game. The designated host detects the disconnection, and sends out an invite to the dropout using `addPlayersToMatch`. The inviteHandler of the dropout has been set at the start, and it fires. The dropout gets the invite and calls what seems to be the standard code:

```
GKMatchmakerViewController *mmvc
mmvc = [[GKMatchmakerViewController alloc] initWithInvite:_pendingInvite];
mmvc.matchmakerDelegate = self;
[_presentingViewController presentViewController:mmvc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

On the dropout machine the MatchMakerViewController duly appears, and it only shows the players already in the match, and they soon are marked "Ready". However the controller shows the message "Waiting for game to start...", and `didFindMatch` is never fired. There is no UI to start the game (the only button is Cancel in the top left).

The weird thing is on the host machine `inviteeResponseHandler` does fire and so it seems the host got the message that the dropout is back. I am calling `finishMatchmakingForMatch` here, but it doesn't seem to do anything.

So how do I tell my dropout to dismiss the MatchMakerViewController?

Tearing my hair out!

Answer (score 0):

Are you handling the did find match method in the matchmaker delegate?

(Note my code is in swift) but you can easily port it to obj c

// A peer-to-peer match has been found, the game should start

```
public func matchmakerViewController(viewController:  GKMatchmakerViewController!, didFindMatch match: GKMatch!)
{
    println("didFindMatch");
    if (!_matchStarted && match.expectedPlayerCount == 0) {
        match.delegate = self;
        mmvc.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true,completion:completedBlock);
    }

}
```